# The Python file problems

Tags: python

```
FileName = input("Please enter the name of your text file: ")
APPEND = "a"
WRITE = "w"
File = (FileName + ".txt")

List = []
Name = " "
while Name != "DONE" :
    Name = input("Please enter the guest name (Enter DONE if there is no more names) : ").upper()
    List.append(Name)
List.remove("DONE")
print("The guests list in alphabetical order, and it will save in " + FileName + " :")
List.sort()
for U in List :
    print(U)
File = open(FileName , mode = APPEND)
File.write(U)
File.close()
print("File written successfully.")
```

Ok guys, I am sorry that I am asking this question over and over, but it annoys me. I don't see any bugs through the code, but the list from the text file ONLY APPEARS ONE NAME. Thanks!

Comment: You are writing `U` to the file which is the last name in the `List`. You need to `File.write(List)`

Comment: One more advice: Please follow the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is this:

```
with open(FileName , mode = APPEND) as f:
  for U in List :
    print(U)
    f.write(U)
    f.write("\n")

print("File written successfully.")
```

using `with` will allow you to open the file, and python with automatically close it for you should an exception occur while it's in use. You want to open the file *before* you enter your loop, then *append within* the loop, and finally, print your success message *after closing* the file (outside the `with`). Indentation is important! :)

Comment: Thanks! But I want to ask a question about the part that the words showed in the text file. The names all got bunched up. Thank you, I am beginner. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Right, sorry. f.write(U) does not append a newline. so you'll need to add f.write("\n") after that for a newline character. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as an answer if you believe I've provided a full and complete answer for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the indentation I see above, you are calling the File open, File write, and File close methods *after* the loop `for U in List`. So only the last name will get appended to the file.

(Of course, maybe your indentation is wrong above...)

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the iteration variable 'U' each time, not saving it anywhere. Write the 'U' variable each time to a file and it should work.